# debug pymongo access - [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am trying to access my database on MongoDB from my virtual private server and from my shared hosting account on Godaddy. I follow the same installation steps for pymongo, and I added the public IP for both. The thing is that the connection to the DB works correctly for the virtual private server, but not for the shared hosting, where I get the error `[Errno 111] Connection refused`

Here is the code, only hiding parts from the connection string:

```
from requests import get

ip = get('https://api.ipify.org').content.decode('utf8')
print('My public IP address is: {}'.format(ip))

from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient

uri = "mongodb+srv://XXXXXX@cluster0.XXXX.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority&ssl=true&ssl_cert_reqs=CERT_NONE"

# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(uri)

# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Here is the output of the virtual private server:

`My public IP address is: 166.62.100.113 Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!`

And here is the output from the shared hosting:

`My public IP address is: 198.71.231.19 XXXX.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused,XXXX.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused,XXXX.mongodb.net:27017: [Errno 111] Connection refused`

I made sure both IPs are added to the access list.

[image]

So, the question is, how can I debug the connection and know what causes it to be refused? Maybe there is some kind of firewall or proxy at GoDaddy that I should be adding? Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your hosting server is likely blocking the mongodb port.

To debug, connect to a shell on the server and the use `mongosh` / `mongo` with the connection string to test. If it connects, chances are your program will connect too.

Comment: I think this is the situation really. I was talking for a few hours with them yesterday and it was not clear. I'll try this approach you suggested. But do you think there can be an way to send an HTTP request to MongoDB cluster, that I can simulate with curl? There seems to be something, but not clear enough

Comment: This seems to be the case. If you cannot change the inbound and outbound rules for the shared hosting, a simple way to get around would be just run a simple flask api wrap that wraps all your crud operations running on the same server instance as your db and query your db using HTTP API calls from your shared account.